# Android: Published App not visibile anymore on Google Play Store

Tags: apk, publish, android, google-play

I'm really a patient man (else I would not be a good programmer), but this time it's all about time.
I've published my app on Monday noon and as always after two or three hours it was visible on Google Play Store. Then, on the next day noon (yesterday) I've published a new apk, because I had to make some corrections. In the afternoon I tried to find it (I searched by App Name, by "App Name" and Developer Name) on Google Play, but it was not there anymore, till today I just cannot find it.
So I wrote yesterday in the afternoon through the developers console an email to google regarding this problem, but no answer until today.
If my app would not be allowed, then I would get a removal email/message, but I got none.
And also from the beginning the Google Play Store Link "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devname.appname" shows "We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server."
So my questions are:
1. Is there anything else I can do from my side?
2. Is there a certain contact name on Google I could contact?

Comment: Check if you have selected correct country/region

Comment: I did check "Select all countries" from the start, because this app should be available in all countries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got an email from Google today. There was nothing wrong on my side. They did not mention the specific error on their side but they fixed it, so now my app is available on Google Play.

Google also mentioned, that they have a chat for these kind of problems to help you instantly and I thought I might share it here with the people in need: 
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/publishing
Just click "Contact Us" at the top right corner.
Support is available only in English from 11 am till 5 pm PT.